# When I insert the data in db its not inserting in order why?

Tags: node.js, angular

i want to insert the array of three and array of two content in db table. when i try to insert first one of the three things is inserted and first one of two things inserted and one thing is inserted and then second content of three things and second content of two things in inserted. I want to insert the all the three content in three things in table and then want to insert the all two things in table.

```
var threeThings = JSON.parse(body.threethings);
var collectThreeThings=[]
async.forEach(threeThings, (item, next) => {
 
     var threeThingsList = {};           
        threeThingsList['uniqueid'] = random;
        threeThingsList['content'] = item.content;
        threeThingsList['type'] = 1;
        threeThingsList['created_at'] = getdbdate;
        collectThreeThings.push(threeThingsList);
        next();
 
}, () => {
    createrecord(models, collectThreeThings, 'sigaram_myreflectioncontentdetails', (res) => {
    })      
})
var twoThings = JSON.parse(body.twothings);
var collectTwoThings=[]
async.forEach(twoThings, (item, next) => {
    var twoThingsList = {};
        twoThingsList['uniqueid'] = random;
        twoThingsList['content'] = item.content;
        twoThingsList['type'] = 2;
        twoThingsList['created_at'] = getdbdate;
        collectTwoThings.push(twoThingsList);
        next();  
}, () => {
    createrecord(models, collectTwoThings, 'sigaram_myreflectioncontentdetails', (res) => {
    })
})

var oneThing ={
    uniqueid:random,
    content:body.onething,
    type:3,
    created_at:getdbdate
}
createrecord(models, oneThing, 'sigaram_myreflectioncontentdetails', (res) => {
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the syntax of `async.forEach` is doing, but I assume it's just doing an asynchronous forEach on each of the two arrays. The rest of my answer will be assuming this, let me know if it's incorrect.

The behaviour you have described is what one should expect from async code, which is that it can happen out of the order in which it is written, somewhat simultaneously.

Try changing the code to something like the following, to remove the asynchronous aspect so that it happens in the order that you are intending.

```js
var threeThings = JSON.parse(body.threethings);
var collectThreeThings = threeThings.map(item => {
     return {
        uniqueid: random,
        content: item.content,
        type: 1,
        created_at: getdbdate,
     }
});
createrecord(models, collectThreeThings, 'sigaram_myreflectioncontentdetails', (res) => {})
```

then do a similar thing for the `twoThings` array.

Comment: Same issue when i try this code also @Ashley